# Why does mongoexport query with $exist fail?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am trying to mongoexport (Version 2.6) MongoDB data into csv format using the command as follows

```
mongoexport --port 27017 -d test -q "{userId:{$exists:true} , name:'John'}"-c user_datas -f userId --csv -o /myOutFile.csv
```

and i got this error message:

```
assertion: 16619 code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: First character in field must be [A-Za-z$_]: offset:9 of:{userId:{true},name:John}
```

according to error message that something happened on '$exists' that caused the error . 
whats wrong with my command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invert the quotes:

```
'{userId: {$exists: true} , name: "John"}'
```

Working command:

```
mongoexport \
  --port 27017 \
  -d test \
  -q '{userId: {$exists: true} , name: "John"}' \
  -c user_datas \
  -f userId \
  --csv \
  -o /myOutFile.csv
```